# Guidance Needed with Basic Contact Form?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm totally new to web design and have gotten stuck creating a contact form. FWIW The original 'frame' of the site came from a template I downloaded.

This is what my form looks like on the index.html side of things:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <form action="contact.php" method="post">

   <div class="form-group">
   <!--<label for="name">name</label>-->
   <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <!--<label for="email">email</label>-->
   <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <!--<label for="message">message</label>-->
   <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Write a message"> 
   </textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

And this is what the contact.php looks like:

```
 <?php

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

 $to = "exampleemail@gmail.com";
 $subject = "New Contact Us Enquiry";
 $text = "A visitor of ninadaviesopticians.co.uk has submitted the following enquiry.\n\nName:$name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nMessage: $message\n\nPlease respond to this enquiry within 24 hours";

 mail ($to, $subject, $text);
 header("Location:index.html");

 ?>
```

When I fill in the contact form, it sends the email to the desired address and gives me the 'A visitor of.....' text without an issue. However, it leaves 'Name', 'Email' and 'Message' fields blank, as if the user never entered them.

Any ideas? Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields require the "name" attribute to be filled to be sent in POST or GET data, not ID.

So for example, your name field would be this :

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
```

You can have both an id and a name, though the id is not used for posting data.

Ref : http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

To post data via forms, the fields need to have the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
```

The ID is only really useful for client side tools.